# Importing the sql table shows, Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed, table made by laravel migration

Tags: laravel, migration

In Laravel migration, all are working fine. But when I export this table and import in new db, this table shows Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed.

sales.sql

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 05, 2020 at 08:19 PM
-- Server version: 10.4.8-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.3.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `inventory_management`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `sales`
--

CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sales_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sub_total` double NOT NULL,
  `discount` double NOT NULL,
  `discount_type` enum('percent','amount') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tax` double NOT NULL,
  `tax_type` enum('percent','amount') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `grand_total` double NOT NULL,
  `payment_type` enum('no-payment','partial-payment','full-payment') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `payment_term_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('paid','void','cancelled','overdue','unpaid') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_item_wise_discount` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_item_wise_tax` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `sales`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `sales_sales_no_unique` (`sales_no`),
  ADD KEY `sales_payment_term_id_index` (`payment_term_id`),
  ADD KEY `sales_created_by_index` (`created_by`),
  ADD KEY `sales_updated_by_index` (`updated_by`),
  ADD KEY `sales_customer_id_index` (`customer_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `sales`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=35;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `sales`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_created_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_payment_term_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`payment_term_id`) REFERENCES `payment_terms` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

But all are working fine, When I alter table and do php artisan migrate. It works. The only problem is when exporting table and importing the table in new db. Thank You in advance

Comment: do the other tables exist that this table is referencing?

Answer (score 0):

are you migrating just one table or the all database? if its just one table, Make sure the other tables exist in the new database with the parent table having information that the other table depending on it needs. let me say if you are migrating `sales.sql` and its information depends on users say( it has a `users_id`), then the new database must have the users table in it. Also mind about the datatypes of the column values you are relating in both tables.

Comment: yes all other table already exist.  What I am doing is that, I've done some changes in this table in local, so to update in server, I exported this particular table only, and deleted the table with this name 'sales' in server in order to import this updated table from localhost. The error pops when I import this new table.
Or, this error pops when only single table with foreignKey imports done without other table? should I have to export all other table too at once? If I do so, all the real data in server would be diappear.

Comment: Try to check the datatypes of the column values. You might find that in the parent table you have ```bigInt``` and ```unsigned```, then in the other table its Just ```int```, try checking the datatypes and verify if they are the same.